# AWS CloudFront for Ddos attacks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-waf

I am using AWS cloudfront for serving my content for java based web application.
When I access my content via cloud front my application is working fine, but when I route my whole web application via cloud front it's giving the following error.
ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.
This distribution is not configured to allow the HTTP request method that was used for this request. The distribution supports only cachable requests. 
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: 4XzY7bSuqBbiTuwbQZKgpVdLpPru5PZ-4oPDWqwvB_FgIbTIsdZJaA==

I want to use AWS cloudfront for avoid DDos attacks for my Java based web application(whole application).
it would be great if anyone helps me with this

Thanks in advance
Sateesh

Answer (score 1):

You've disallowed POST to your distribution but you actually did a POST from the client. Please edit your distribution and under the 'Behaviors' tab, please select 'GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE' for Allowed HTTP Methods. You have probably currently selected 'GET, HEAD'